# Entity Framework ProxyCreation disabled but still need access to some related record data

Tags: entity-framework

Following some advice from StackOverflow, I turned off ProxyCreation in my dbContext using the code below to solve the circular reference problem

```
_dbcontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

After turning it off, Json serialization return null of my related type which was expected to solve the circular reference but what if i still need certain type. For example i have access to EntityParentType from my EntityChild

EntityChild.EntityParentType (which they are related in database as foreign key relationship, EntityParenetTypeId).

I tried .Include("EntityParentType") but i get back the circular reference problem again. What is the right way to get this done?

```
    var result = from entry in EntityChild.Include("EntityParentType")
                 where entry.EntityParentTypeId == 1 
                 select entry;
```

Edited: Is using ViewModel the best option to solve this circular reference problem? http://garfbradazweb.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/mvc-3-entity-framework-and-serializing-jsoncircular-references/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ignore parent or child in the serialization using [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) attribute,

```
public class Entity
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Item ChildEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this is not a good option for me cause i'm using database first and my models are generated. I'm looking for something more flexible where i can turn on and off the "including". Thanks for the suggestion though. Appreciate that ;)

Comment: I think your approach should work with include, the circular references error means your data is wrong (may be). Because it seems like your parent.parent.parent ... is referring again to a child

Comment: ya, it's a EntryItem>EntryCode>UserGroup>User>EntryRecord>"EntryItem" again... i think this is normal design of table. is it abnormal to have circular relationship?

Comment: No it's not , but you can just ignore one attribute in the middle or not use include to avoid circular reference . It's depends on the data that you need in the client. Do you need all of them at once ?

Comment: i don't need all of them at once but at diff scenario i need "EntryItem>EntryCode>" and on certain scenario "EntryCode>UserGroup" and "UserGroup>User>EntryRecord>EntryItem"

Comment: Feels like you are getting too much info at once :) .

Comment: I'm following your example [ScriptIgnore] public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; } but when i hit debug, it still using proxy. anything i missed?

Comment: Did you added the `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` before the query?

Comment: once i set ProxyCreationEnabled = false, i got back to ground zero - non of the related element can be included...